# python import a module with source code in temporary file

Tags: python, temp

```
import tempfile

tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
try:
    # do stuff with temp
    tmp.write(b'def fun():\n\tprint("hello world!")\n')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        func = __import__(tmp.name)
        func.fun()
finally:
    tmp.close()  # deletes the file
```

So I want to create a temporary file, add some source code to it and then import the module and call the function, but I always run into this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '/var/folders/3w/yyp887lx4018h9s5sr0bwhkw0000gn/T/tmp84bk0bic'
```

It doesn't seem to find the module of the temporary file. How do I solve this?

Comment: The temp module file probably is not in any directory mentioned in the `PYTHON_PATH`.  How about putting the temp module file next to your main script file and importing it from there?  That should be possible.

Comment: @Alfe not sure how to do that, going to the docs to see how I can do that

Comment: Why write this stuff into a file instead of just `eval("your code here")`?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. Your filename does not end with `.py`, but Python modules are expected to.  You can fix this by setting `suffix='.py'` in `NamedTemporaryFile()`.
2. `__import__()` is not the right way to load a module from a full path.  See here: [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)
3. You do not flush after writing and before importing, so even if Python does find the file, it may well be empty.  Add `tmp.flush()` after writing to fix this.

Comment: according to @Alfe I created the file in the current directory as that of the script itself, I tried flushing too, I also gave a name to the file with `.py` extension, still getting the same error

Comment: @J.Doe: Are you still using `__import__()`?  You should not.

Comment: yeah I was at the time

Answer (score 1):

Importing can only be done from certain directories which are part of the `PYTHON_PATH`.  You can extend that.  Then you will have to use `__import__()` with a module name (not a path in the file system).  You will have to deal with the suffix for the temp file.

I implemented a simple version using the local directory for the temp module file and a version using a proper tempfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import tempfile

SCRIPT = '''\
def fun():
  print("hello world!")
'''

# simple version using the local directory:
with open('bla.py', 'w') as tmp_module_file:
  tmp_module_file.write(SCRIPT)
import bla
bla.fun()

# version using the tempfile module:    
tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.py', delete=True)
try:
  tmpfile.write(SCRIPT.encode('utf8'))
  tmpfile.flush()
  tmpmodule_path, tmpmodule_file_name = os.path.split(tmpfile.name)
  tmpmodule_name = tmpmodule_file_name[:-3]  # strip off the '.py'
  sys.path.append(tmpmodule_path)
  tmpmodule = __import__(tmpmodule_name)
finally:
  tmpfile.close()
tmpmodule.fun()
```